# What qualifies as next-of-kin for a US SF-180, Request Pertaining to Military Records?

Tags: united-states, military-records, kinship-terminology

The [SF 180](https://www.archives.gov/files/sf180-request-pertaining-to-military-records-exp-april2018-1.pdf) seems to conflict itself on what qualifies as next-of-kin.

***The instructions, lacking "grandchild", state this:***

> [image]

---

***However, the fillable form has a drop-down field for next-of-kin, and that includes "grandchild".***

> [image]

---

Which one is correct?

Are grandchildren considered to be next-of-kin for the purpose of this form or not?  Why is there a discrepancy?